# Control access in afterSave Parse Server to modify User

Tags: flutter, parse-server

In my App a User should write some data a class (named `Contributions`) and after that an `afterSave` trigger should add a relation from that user to the data. Therefore, I use

```
final contribution = ParseObject('Contributions')
      ..set('contribution', newContrib)
      ..set('roundId', round.toPointer())
      ..set('commonId', common.toPointer())
      ..set('userId', user.toPointer())
      ..setACL(ParseACL(owner: user));
```

After the data is saved an `afterSave` call is triggered. In this call I want to add a relation from the `User` to the new added data in `Contributions`. However, even though I specified the ACL (see upper), the `afterSave` does not save the new relation due to

I tried the following which leads to `Parse error:  Cannot modify user Yd9uidQxz9.` However, I expected to be able to modify the User since I added ACL in my Flutter code.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Contributions", async (request) => {
  const contribution = request.object.get('contribution');
  const round = request.object.get('roundId');
  await round.fetch();
  
  const user = request.object.get('userId');
  await user.fetch();

  const query = new Parse.Query('Rounds');
  
  query.get(round.id).then(
    function(round) {
    round.increment('contribution', contribution);
    round.save();
  }).then(function(savedRound) {
      const userRelation = user.relation('contributions');
      userRelation.add(request.object);
      return user.save();
    }).catch(function(error) {
    throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
  });
});
```

Comment: That could be a problem related to ACL or CLA for User table or User's row in the table. You may try to use MasterKey on save of user